# How do I copy rows with certain criteria from multiple spreadsheets into one spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I made a Google Form for assigning a task to myself or a colleague.

For Example:

> spreadsheet name: Science, Column 1=Name 2=task 3=due date
>   spreadsheet name: Mathematics, Column 1=Name 2=task 3=due date

What I need to do is search each spreadsheet (that these forms create) for my name. Then copy the whole row that my name is on so i have all my tasks in one place without having to keep opening every spreadsheet and looking for my name.

Answer (score 1):

To search for an entry in any Google product, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, and (usually) a find bar will appear in the upper right hand corner of the screen. To copy the whole row, you click on the row (i.e. Row D), which highlights the row. Right click on that row and select 'copy' from the drop-down menu.